# Gstreamer record webcam audio and video sync

Tags: camera, gstreamer, webcam, video-capture

I'm using Gstreamer to record audio+video from a webcam to a file, and their sync is off. I can see a delay in playback from the MKV file.

Can someone see a problem in my command?

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0 -m -e -v 
mfvideosrc device-name="Logitech MeetUp"  do-timestamp=true
! "image/jpeg," "width=3840," "height=2160," "framerate=30/1," "pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1"
! queue ! nvjpegdec ! queue ! nvh264enc preset=hp qp-min=23 ! queue ! h264parse ! queue ! mkv.

wasapisrc device="{audio_device_stringified}"
! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 ! mkv. 

matroskamux name=mkv 
! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 ! filesink location=out.mkv
```